# Create a "wait message" in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

I need to create a "wait message" in jsp page for x time, after pressing on the button and before the next page opens.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="javascript">
function doBeforeSubmit()
{
  document.getElementById("displayBeforeSubmit").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("displayAfterSubmit").style.dispay = "block";
  return true; // you must return true or the form will not submit
}
</script>

<div id="displayBeforeSubmit">
<form action="results_page.jsp" method="post"
onsubmit="doBeforeSubmit()">
...
form stuff
...
</form>
</div>

<div id="displayAfterSubmit">
<h3>Please wait...</h3>
</div>
```

I hope that gives you an idea. In my opinion, you should try this "Please Wait" part in Javascript.

Comment: Dear Soner Gonul, i need to create a page that load for some 4 seconds then redirect to another page any help ???

Comment: or can i create a pop up window that shows for some 4 seconds and then display the other page requested ???? thank for your help in advance

Comment: You can use _setTimeout_ Look at these articles [1](http://www.geekpedia.com/KB55_How-do-I-make-a-JavaScript-function-wait-before-executing-%28sleep-or-delay%29.html) [2](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/timers)